# How safe is createuuid in a clustered environment?

Tags: coldfusion

The title pretty much says it all. The scenario is a user uploads a file but they could be hitting 1 of 6 servers depending on the current load at the time. We have run into a situation where the users are trying to upload files with special characters in their names. We can write a function to sanitize the file name but then we have to check that the new sanitized file name doesn't exists. My thought was to just rename the file using createuuid(). I believe the createuuid() function uses the servername as part of the algorithm if I remember correctly so if anything, the uniqueness should be 6 fold due to the 6 servers. Am I correct in this thinking?

Comment: You are correct.  I'm in a slightly different situation and find that the cftoken, cfid, and gettickcount combinations are good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, CF uses timestamp+clock+servername.

Did you consider sanitizing the uploaded filename and just append the UUID? This appears failproof to me.

Comment: Yes, but the length of the file name stored in the DB becomes an issue. The DB is replicated by the client so we are trying to minimize changes to the DB schema as much as possible.

Comment: What length does the field have? UUID without dashes has 32 characters, so you could easily go `left(sanitizedFileName, (MAX_LENGTH - 32))`.

Comment: It's not that we can't change it, it just makes things a little more complicated not to mention it causes the client some grief which we'd prefer not to do. :) But you do make a good point about removing the dashes.